# SQL timeouts at 3 minutes past full hour

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem that has puzzled me for a while now. Once in a while, say 4-5 times a week we get timeouts from the database at HH:03 (or HH:02 sometimes I think).
I've been digging into the scheduled tasks on the server to investigate if there is something that puts the server to it's knees in performance without any findings.

I've also gone so fas so that I've made a watchdog for the application so that when the query only has 1 seconds left of it's max query time it checks the processlist for the database and emails this to me. The process list always contains just one entry and that's the entry that is about to get an timeout exception.

To further add to the complexity we have many customers to this application but it's only one of the customers that get this timeout. All customers run the same code but have different databases, different application pools with different application pool identities.

The application is an ASP.net application. The database is a Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 Express edition.

Has anyone heard of something like this? Can anyone give me any pointers about what to investigate in order to resolve this issue?

Kind regards

Comment: Well, this probably doesn't belong on Stackoverflow as it's not a programming question, but I would start by looking at the backup mechanism for the database. Also check event logs to see if there is always something running/logging at that time

Comment: Besides @SpectralGhost tips, if you know that it happens almost daily at a specific time do a profile on the database and check the appropriate events and columns in order to catch the issue (some recompile, database reindex, dbcc checks...)

Comment: +1 on the trace idea because I have to think this is a case of that one customer passing in a request that retrieves an unusually large set of data. If this connection is calling a stored procedure, it is possible SQL Server has cached an optimal plan for the other 99% of requests it gets for the proc, but perhaps this one customer is calling the proc in either a different way (different optional parameters) or it simply retrieves more data than the cached plan expects, resulting in sub-optimal operations within the plan steps.